# How does PulseAudio determine which ALSA devices to make available or not?

Tags: linux, pulseaudio, alsa

PulseAudio usually does a pretty good job of determining what ALSA devices are available and setting them up automatically.  When it doesn't, I'm not clear how this seemingly automatic linkage occurs.  Is it a push where ALSA tells PulseAudio about the devices or a pull where PulseAudio determines from the ALSA configuration?  Let's say you've got 3 audio 'cards': A, B and C.  `aplay -l` shows all three (assume all three are working as expected via aplay) but `pacmd list-cards` only shows A and B.  If you only wanted PulseAudio to use B and C, how would you get PulseAudio to remove A and add C?  I assume this would be done via `pacmd` and/or changing PA's startup configuration files but I'm not clear as to how exactly to do this.

Comment: Without looking up details: Pulseaudio executes a startup script, which calls modules to either include all ALSA hardware (default), or specific ALSA cards (you need to modify the script accordingly, and use a different module).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that modules are responsible for adding devices. E.g. there is one called `module-udev-detect`, and if I do `pacmd list-cards` in my system, I see `module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"` in two out of the three. The third one is a bluetooth device, so I guess that one comes from the `bluez5` module.

Looking at the web a bit, you can make pulseaudio ignore a device coming from udev by setting `ENV{PULSE_IGNORE}="1"` in a udev rule. See

- https://jamielinux.com/blog/tell-pulseaudio-to-ignore-a-usb-device-using-udev/ and
- https://github.com/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/blob/5f727f0faf4c37794da6719941ab975252325888/src/modules/module-udev-detect.c#L453)

I guess that for bluetooth you'd have to fiddle with bluez, to ignore the device.

As to why a device can get ignored, that can be because it was locked (alsa devices can only be open once) when pulseaudio tried to open it.

Edit from @blihp:

To force PulseAudio to attempt to use an audio device, add an entry to `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

```
load-module module-alsa-sink device=plughw:<card#>,<device#>
```

(replace `<card#>,<device#>` with the specific hardware for your system such as `0,1`)